# React Native: How to stop map markers from re-rendering on every state update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have a component that has a map with multiple custom markers for various locations and a carousel with cards for those same locations. When a user presses a marker, it should show the callout and show the location's name next to the marker (but outside of the callout).

However, because I update the state in `onRegionChangeComplete`, if the user moves the map and then quickly presses the marker (before the state finishes updating from calling `setState` in `onRegionChangeComplete`), then the markers will re-render before firing the `onPress` event, and the event is never fired.

One solution might be to use `shouldComponentUpdate`, however, the docs state that it should only be used for performance optimization and not to prevent re-renders (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), but more importantly, my `componentDidUpdate` function has some conditional logic dependent on the region set in `shouldComponentUpdate`, as well as other conditional actions, so I don't want to prevent re-rendering of the entire component, just unnecessary re-rendering of the markers.

I'm also using the performance optimization mentioned in https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2082 of wrapping the makers in a component that implements `shouldComponentUpdate` and `getDerivedStateFromProps`, however, I'm not entirely sure this is doing anything because it seems like the parent component is just recreating all of my optimized markers rather than using their optimizations to handle re-rendering. Also, even if I don't use a wrapped marker but a conventional custom marker, I still have the same issues.

I've also opened an issue for this on react-native-maps but haven't gotten a response yet: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2860

My 'onRegionComplete' function that updates state when map is moved. I removed a few other conditional state updates for brevity:

```
onRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
    const nextState = { };
    nextState.region = region;

    if (this.state.showNoResultsCard) {
      nextState.showNoResultsCard = false;
    }

    .
    .
    .

    this.setState({ ...nextState });

    this.props.setSearchRect({
      latitude1: region.latitude + (region.latitudeDelta / 2),
      longitude1: region.longitude + (region.longitudeDelta / 2),
      latitude2: region.latitude - (region.latitudeDelta / 2),
      longitude2: region.longitude - (region.longitudeDelta / 2)
    });
  }
```

MapView using the more conventional marker (not the optomized version):

```
<MapView // show if loaded or show a message asking for location
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={{ flex: 1, minHeight: 200, minWidth: 200 }}
    initialRegion={constants.initialRegion}
    ref={this.mapRef}
    onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
    showsUserLocationButton={false}
    showsPointsOfInterest={false}
    showsCompass={false}
    moveOnMarkerPress={false}
    onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
    customMapStyle={mapStyle}
    zoomTapEnabled={false}
    >

        {this.state.isMapReady && this.props.places.map((place, index) => {
            const calloutText = this.getDealText(place, 'callout');
            return (
                <Marker
                    tracksViewChanges
                    key={Shortid.generate()}
                    ref={(ref) => { this.markers[index] = ref; }}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: place.getLatitude(),
                        longitude: place.getLongitude()
                    }}
                    onPress={() => { this.onMarkerSelect(index); }}
                    anchor={{ x: 0.05, y: 0.9 }}
                    centerOffset={{ x: 400, y: -60 }}
                    calloutOffset={{ x: 8, y: 0 }}
                    calloutAnchor={{ x: 0.075, y: 0 }}
                    image={require('../../Assets/icons8-marker-80.png')}
                    style={index === this.state.scrollIndex ? { zIndex: 2 } : null}
                >
               {this.state.scrollIndex === index &&
                    <Text style={styles.markerTitle}>{place.getName()}</Text>}

                  <Callout onPress={() => this.onCalloutTap(place)} tooltip={false}>
                    <View style={{
                      borderColor: red,
                      width: 240,
                      borderWidth: 0,
                      borderRadius: 20,
                      paddingHorizontal: 8,
                      flexDirection: 'column',
                      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                      alignItems: 'center'
                    }}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.Title}>Now:</Text>
                      <View style={{
                        width: 240,
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                        alignItems: 'flex-start',
                        paddingHorizontal: 8,
                        flex: 1
                      }}
                      >
                        {calloutText.Text}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Callout>
        </Marker>
        );
    }) 
}

</MapView>
```

My function for the marker's on press event:

```
onMarkerSelect(index) {
    this.setState({ scrollIndex: index });
    this.carousel._component.scrollToIndex({
      index,
      animated: true,
      viewOffset: 0,
      viewPosition: 0.5
    });

    this.markers[index].redrawCallout();
}
```

Updating state and then quickly pressing a marker will cause the onPress event not to fire. Also, the markers are re-rendered/recreated every time a parent component is updated. (I say recreated because it seems like the markers are re-rendering without even firing `shouldComponentUpdat`e or `componentDidUpdate`).

Is there any way to update state in `onRegionChangeComplete` without forcing the markers to re-render?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? Let us know the workaround for this. I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: @Balasubramanian The problem was that I was randomly generating the keys for the markers, so the parent component was recreating them every time it re-rendered. I described this in the github issue that I created and linked to in the question (#2860), so hopefully you've already seen that and solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who happens to have this problem, the issue was that I was randomly generating the keys for the markers, causing the parent component to create new markers each time it was re-rendered.

Specifically, the line `key={Shortid.generate()}` was the problem.